# Get report from JasperServer using SOAP

Tags: java, soap, jasperserver

Can someone provide me a working example which gets reports from jasperserver using it's SOAP API. 
Actually I know how to run it to a file.... but I need to get report data directly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried a lot of ways of doing the above thing, and what I've came up with is to get report from JasperServer in JasperPrint format and then export it in whatever you need. Another way of solving that problem is to get report via HTTP API.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/JavaScriptSOAPClient.aspx

But I had the same issue of having to go to jasperserver direct.  If you're doing this on a PHP server they have quite a bit of PHP demo code that does the SOAP call for you.  I used that and found it far easier to implement than doing it with JavaScript.  The above link though should help you with making the SOAP call.

I found Jaspers SOAP documentation lacking so having the PHP source code that did a working example was quite helpful.