# JasperReports Server and Swing - How to access repository/report from server

Tags: java, swing, repository, jasperserver

I'm looking for a solution how to fill a report that is not local on my computer, but on a JasperReports Server.

Is there any example for getting a connection to a Repository or a Report on the Jasperserver?

it should be something like,**Pseudo-code**:

```
Map<String,Object> jasperParameter = new HashMap<String,Object>();

String linkToMyRepository="localhost:8080/jasperserver/repository"    

RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService("linkToMyRepository");

JasperReport report = (JasperReport)service.getResource("myreport");

JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, jasperParameter, con);
```

This is only **pseudo-code**, can someone help me out?

Thanks alot!

Comment: You can view this article: http://www.exoplatform.com/company/en/resource-viewer/Tutorial/how-to-generate-pdf-files-from-exo-platform-nodetype-using-jasperreports

Comment: You can also read http://jasperserver.sourceforge.net/docs/3-7-0/JasperServer-Web-Services-Guide.pdf and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4016359/get-report-from-jasperserver-using-soap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved!

```
JServer server = new JServer();

        server.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/services/repository");

        server.setUsername("username");

        server.setPassword("password");

        WSClient client = new WSClient(server);

        ResourceDescriptor resourceDescriptor = new ResourceDescriptor();

        resourceDescriptor.setUriString ("/reports/myreportname");

        Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        parameterMap.put("MY_PARAMETER_NAME", "myparametervalue");

        JasperPrint printer = client.runReport(resourceDescriptor, parameterMap);

        JasperViewer.viewReport(printer, false, Locale.GERMAN);
```

Comment: When I try to use this code I get this error: The method runReport(ResourceDescriptor, Map<String,Object>, List<Argument>) in the type WSClient is not applicable for the arguments 
 (ResourceDescriptor, Map<String,Object>) - I guess they changed the API.  Does anyone have an updated code sample?

Comment: try this:

 JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameterMap, new JRMapCollectionDataSource(list));

the list can be null (I guess), because I am passing data in this list to the report